# Saving ListView items in a text file in c#

Tags: c#, listview, export-to-text

From the following code I am trying to save listView items in a text file. But it doesn't save the items of listView in text file even not generating any error. My listView has a single column. Please identify What I am missing in this code.

```
private void saveAttemptsStatus()
    {            
        var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\AlphaNumDataSum_" + txt_LUsername.Text);
        foreach (ListViewItem item in list_Count.Items)
        {

            sw.Write(item + "\r\n");               
        }
        sw.Close();
    }    
private void CountAttemps()
    {
        int numberOfItems = list_Count.Items.Count;
        if (numberOfItems != 10)
                {
                    if (username == txt_LUsername.Text && password == txt_LPassword.Text)
                    {
                        list_Count.Items.Add("correct");
                        txt_LUsername.Text = string.Empty;
                        txt_LPassword.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        list_Count.Items.Add("inCorrect");
                        txt_LUsername.Text = string.Empty;
                        txt_LPassword.Text = string.Empty;
                    }
                    }
                else
                {
                    saveAttemptsStatus();
                    MessageBox.Show("Thank You!");

                }
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the code that is calling the saveAttemptsStatus function?

Comment: @ShaiAharoni I have added that code.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your code to the following version and see if this works:

```
private void saveAttemptsStatus()
    {    
        var filePath = "D:\\AlphaNumDataSum_" + txt_LUsername.Text;

        using(sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath)){

            foreach (ListViewItem item in list_Count.Items)
            {
              sw.WriteLine(item.Text);               
            }
        }   
    }
```

Comment: Same issue exists.

Answer (score 0):

I have sorted it out by creating a new file.

```
private void saveAttemptsStatus()
    {
        try
        {
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\AlphaNumDataSum_" + txt_LUsername.Text + "_Attempts");
            foreach (ListViewItem item in list_Count.Items)
            {
                sw.Write(item + "\r\n");
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
        catch (System.IO.FileNotFoundException ex)
        {
            System.IO.File.Create("D:\\AlphaNumDataSum_" + txt_LUsername.Text + "_Attempts");
            var sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter("D:\\AlphaNumDataSum_" + txt_LUsername.Text + "_Attempts");
            foreach (ListViewItem item in list_Count.Items)
            {
                sw.Write(item + "\r\n");
            }
            sw.Close();
        }
    }
```